# Validation with Symfony2 and Propel

Tags: symfony, propel

I've recently started using symfony2 and propel for a project. It's not a smooth ride but its coming along ok.

A few nights ago, I got stuck with form validations. I have my validation.yml defined as such:

```
Project\MainBundle\Model\User:
    properties:
        first_name:
            - NotBlank: { message: "Please add the user's first name." }
        last_name:
            - NotBlank: { message: "Please add the user's last name." }
        email: 
            - NotBlank: { message: "Please add the user's email address." }
            - Email: { message: "Please use a valid email address." }
        password: 
            - NotBlank: { message: "Please add the user's email address." }
```

When I submit the form everything works fine except for when the form submits with a blank first_name and last_name. I found out after debugging, that the problem is not on the validation but rather on the rendering of the errors for the two fields. Password and Email errors render ok. Here's how I setup my form.

```
    $builder->add('firstName', 'text');
    $builder->add('lastName', 'text');
    $builder->add('email', 'text');
    $builder->add('password', 'password');
```

I can just change how I name my fields on the form builder but at the same time I want to follow symfony2's naming convention (and my database naming convention stays) so I am opting for this as a last resort.

I hope I explained my problem clearly. Can anyone provide me with a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can validate by getters.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#getters

```
Project\MainBundle\Model\User:
    getter:
        firstName:
            - NotBlank: { message: "Please add the user's first name." }
        lastName:
            - NotBlank: { message: "Please add the user's last name." }
        email: 
            - NotBlank: { message: "Please add the user's email address." }
            - Email: { message: "Please use a valid email address." }
        password: 
            - NotBlank: { message: "Please add the user's email address." }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may come from the fact that you don't seem to respect the YAML syntax.

```
Project\MainBundle\Model\User:
    properties:
        first_name:
            - NotBlank: { message: Please add the user's first name. }
        last_name:
            - NotBlank: { message: "Please add the user's last name. }
        email: 
            - NotBlank: { message: Please add the user's email address. }
            - Email: { message: Please use a valid email address. }
        password: 
            - NotBlank: { message: Please add the user's email address.}
```

You can refer to: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html